# How to assign values to a variable with bind_result and fetch?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get values from my database and assign them to a variable. This is my code.

```
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT ngno, email, encrypted_password, name, user_type FROM `guide` WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($ngno, $email, $encrypted_password, $name, $user_type);
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($encrypted_password == $password){
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
```

i need to assign the values from my table to the variable $user and return it to my login.php file.

```
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

if ($user != false) {
    // use is found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["ngno"] = $user["ngno"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];  
    $response["user"]["user_type"] = $user["user_type"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

my code doesnt seem to assign values into the $user variable. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the following statement in `getUserByEmailAndPassword()` method,

```
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

`fetch()` method fetches results from a prepared statement into the bound variables, and the method actually returns `true` or `false`.

Here's the reference:

- [mysqli_stmt::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Instead create an array, say `$user` and push those bound variable values into the array. And finally return the array from the method.

So your `getUserByEmailAndPassword()` method should be like this:

```
public  function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT ngno, email, encrypted_password, name, user_type FROM `guide` WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($ngno, $email, $encrypted_password, $name, $user_type);
        $user = array();
        if($stmt->fetch()){
            if($encrypted_password == $password){
                $user['ngno'] = $ngno;
                $user['email'] = $email;
                $user['name'] = $name;
                $user['user_type'] = $user_type;

                $stmt->close();
                return $user;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RyanAluvihare Glad I could help. *Cheers!* :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot put a comment, have you tried:

```
var_dump($user);
```

If it returns NULL, check your method getUserByEmailAndPassword, especially this line:

```
$encrypted_password == $password
```

Since your are comparing your $encrypted_password to the $password variable, are you sure that the $password variable you are comparing to is also the encrypted (should be hashed) password? Will be updating this answer once you respond.

Comment: my login.php code works fine because it give correct answer when i use get_result instead of bind_results. both the passwords match. i even checked with a printf statement.. the issue is i believe $user = $stmt->fetch() doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Are the codes above from two different files? how did you put merge the two codes from above? By require_once? If not, you need to use a SESSION.

Comment: updateed the comment. Yes its merged with requir_once.

Comment: try adding [ die( var_dump( $user ) ); ] after the $user = stmt->fetch(); See if it returns NULL, If it does, then you are right. Something is wrong with your fetch() statement.